# Permutations of a boolean array

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, permutation

If I have an array of boolean values of *n* length, how can I iterate over all possible permutations of the array?

For example, for an array of size 3, there are eight possible permutations:

```
[0,0,0]
[0,0,1]
[0,1,0]
[0,1,1]
[1,0,0]
[1,0,1]
[1,1,0]
[1,1,1]
```

P.S. I am working in C, although I'm not necessarily looking for a language specific answer.  Just trying to find an efficient algorithm to do this with large arrays and many possible permutations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement "add 1" in binary:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void add1(int *a, int len) {
  int carry = 1;
  for (int i = len - 1; carry > 0 && i >= 0; i--) {
    int result = a[i] + carry;
    carry = result >> 1;
    a[i] = result & 1;
  }
}

void print(int *a, int len) {
  printf("[");
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (i > 0) printf(",");
    printf("%d", a[i]);
  }
  printf("]\n");
}

int main(void) {
  int a[3] = { 0 };
  int n = sizeof a / sizeof a[0];
  for (int i = 0; i < (1 << n); i++) {
    print(a, n);
    add1(a, n);
  }
}
```

Compile and run:

```
$ gcc foo.c -o foo
$ ./foo
[0,0,0]
[0,0,1]
[0,1,0]
[0,1,1]
[1,0,0]
[1,0,1]
[1,1,0]
[1,1,1]
```

Comment: If I do this am I limited to the bit length of int on my system?  For example if I have 50 items, wouldn't it exceed the number of bits in int[] a?

Comment: @piper1935 Which part of this code do you think is limited to the bit length of int on your system?

Comment: @piper1935 no and no.

Comment: Yes this is limited to `n <= 30` (if you have 32-bit ints), otherwise `1 << n` causes undefined behaviour. The limit could be increased to `n <= 63` with some code modifications.

Comment: @M.M True the little test main is limited to printing 2 billion numbers.  But the add1() function, which is the answer to the question, will work on arrays of length up to 2 billion. If I'd implemented the test main by just checking for the array to wrap back to all zeros, it would cycle through all 2^2billion array values. I for one would not want to wait for it.

Comment: any reason you used `int` instead of a single byte? (or even a single bit)

Comment: @M.M The OP spec'ed an array of booleans and that he was working in C. In C, `int` is used to represent boolean values.  I was just answering the question.

Comment: You mean `int` *can be* used to represent booleans.. as can any other integer type (e.g. `_Bool`)

Answer (score 2):

If you actually need every permutation of the array. A cleaner method can be **std::next_permutation()**

```
do{
    std::cout<<v[0]<<" "<<v[1]<<" "<<v[2]<<" "<<v[3]<<std::endl;
}

while(std::next_permutation(v.begin(),v.end()));
```

Theoretical Complexity will be same as "add 1" or other methods. Plus only STL will do the work for you.

Comment: This is a C question, no C++ involved.

Comment: @Deduplicator, You know, It doesn't hurt to a little bit of C++ too.

Answer (score 1):

to make general C language solution (as soon as question tag is C) for vector of length n you can use binary representation of integer variable i: [0,2^n) where n is length of array and within **single** loop iterate all vectors using bitwise operators.

Comment: Makes sense to use bitwise operators for efficiency.  How would you do the iterations in a single loop?

Comment: for (i = 0; i < 2^n; ++i)

Comment: Gene implemented this algorithm for you.

Comment: @Kaponir `^` is the XOR operator in C

Comment: @M.M From times when I was a student at math faculty I prefer **short** mathematical notation for clarity. maybe because I'm architect, maybe because i work with smart people, not robots.

Answer (score 0):

Using GMP can make this a little easier, particularly if you don't really need actual arrays, just something you can test the bits of:

```
#include <gmp.h>

...
int numbits = 3;  // Insert whatever you want
mpz_t curperm;
mpz_init(curperm);

for (; mpz_sizeinbase(curperm, 2) <= numbits; mpz_add_ui(curperm, curperm, 1)) {
    ... test specific bits w/mpz_tstbit(curperm, #) instead of array check of curperm[#] ...
}

mpz_clear(curperm);
```